# Html5 geolocation getCurrentPosition stopped working

Tags: html, geolocation

I have been using html5 geolocation on my website. but it stopped working now. I have Checked javascript code. Following line is not working 
    `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);`

I have checked on W3Schools [https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation] as well but its not working there as well

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have blocked the browser setting to detect your location.

Comment: I have not blocked location setting. I have checked it on 2 browsers. can you check    on  w3school ? https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

Comment: Yes I have checked now.For me it is showing the location ie latitude and longitude.

Comment: For me location pop-up is appearing but latitude and longitude is not getting  displayed.

Comment: When you get the pop up click on share location and you will get the result displayed.